# Keeping League of Legends questions up to date

Tags: discussion

I am really finding it frustrating keeping my League of Legends questions up to date as patches and new seasons bring huge changes to the games meta, mechanics and options. Examples are new maps, remade pve data (variable mob strength), remade champions, new champions, remade items and new items.

Is there a better way of managing questions like mine here: [What is the optimal way to play the remade Evelynn in the jungle?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15981/what-is-the-optimal-way-to-play-the-remade-evelynn-in-the-jungle#comment132218_15981)

Comment: Clearly should just close all of the Lol/SC2/Dota2 questions for being too localized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is. League of Legends Updates about twice a month, which is undoubtedly going to cause some issues, both since the changes are frequent (though often not wholly drastic), and because we have a lot of questions on the subject.

The best bet is what we've had to make do with for Minecraft in the past (another problem, oft-updated, game) - keep an eye out for old questions, and if they're wrong, either suggest an edit (if the answer requires a small change), notify the author via comment (if you would rather not edit their answer, or don't know the details, other than that something changed), or post an up-to-date answer of your own.

If an update has removed the question entirely, the best bet is to flag it for mod attention as no longer relevant (we will close it as too localized, due to its historic content).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is do a search for `user:<your user id> [tag name]`.  This will give you all of your questions and answers in that tag.  Find which ones need updating and do so.  Of course this doesn't solve the problem of other users' content, although you do have enough rep for unreviewed edits.  Having said that, with something like LoL, worry about being proactive yourself before you worry about others.